# How to clean a new tile floor with single component grout without causing damage to the grout

Tags: tile, cleaning, grout

I installed porcelain floor tile with this [single component grout](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Fusion-Pro-381-Bright-White-1-Gal-Single-Component-Grout-FP3811-2T/203705529). I did the initial cleanup of excess grout with a damp sponge. House cleaners will be coming one week after I installed the grout. How long should I wait after installation to mop the floor, and are there cleaning products that should be avoided in order to prevent damage to the grout?

To be clear, my concern is not how to do the initial cleanup with a wet sponge or how to get the floor looking its best, but rather, how to ensure the grout is not damaged by regular floor cleaning.

Comment: Was going to edit my answer with further detail, but it has been deleted - I cleaned and prepped a large tile floor for an oil treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company says that you do not need to seal it but some users say that it will stain.

So i would use a good sealer on it, wait the time specified on the instructions and then use a mild detergent like [TSP](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SAVOGRAN-1-lb-Box-TSP-Heavy-Duty-Cleaner-10621/202935861) and an [abrasive pad](https://www.tiledoctor.com/products/seal-enhance-care-maintenance/scrub-pads/). Clean with clean warm water and sponge.

(To be fair it is an "Advanced acrylic plus silicone resin formulation" so i do not know how well the sealer will penetrate it.)

Wait a week and seal again and then you should be good to clean it when needed.

It is tile and should not need harsh or extra strong chemical cleaners. Mild soapy water will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Page 6 of the [use and care guide](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/4b/4b836cc6-b788-41bf-bb14-82bf5bb251fe.pdf) states

> Beware of acid-based
>   everyday cleaners!
>   Everyday cleaners that are acid-based — especially those containing lemon, acid, bleach or vinegar — may visibly damage or etch some types of stone, tile and grout. Use everyday cleaners that are non-acidic and non-abrasive, or specially formulated for stone, tile and grout.